# POST asp.net web form to Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms, asp.net-web-api

I need to post a form in a ASP.NET Web Forms application to a Web API. The method I'm trying to use is [System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String, NameValueCollection)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Web API will do model binding only if the posted form field names match the model properties.

But the rendered form has field names like `ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$mainContent$DateOfBirth` or `ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$mainContent$MA_Address_State`

So basically the following does not work:

```
byte[] responseArray = webClient.UploadValues(action, "POST", Request.Form);
```

I guess I could go through all the form controls on client side and convert them to a `NameValueCollection` of my choice, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You may change your ClientID property. You are using the default AutoID value, change it to static. Add following to web.config of your WebForms project:

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static" />
```

[Control.ClientIDMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This makes id and name attributes different. id becomes what we want, and name still remains that long hierarchical with $ symbols. The POST uses the name attribute. Which means model will still not be bound by receiving API.